# Getting an error: "Segmentation fault (Core Dumped)" on my program. Everything working otherwise. Why?

Tags: c++

I'm getting an error "segmentation fault(core dumped)" for my program here, but everything in the program seems to be working fine. I understand what the error signifies I just cant identify what in my code is causing it. Any ideas?

```
#include <cmath> // for use of math functions
#include <iomanip> // for output display
#include "cosc1437_tk_1371133.h"
using namespace std;

//Global Constansts
const int ROWS = 3;
const int COLS = 10;

//Prototypes: None (other than defined in toolkit)

// MAIN program
int main()
{

  // Hello Message
  displayMessage("Hello. This program will demonstrate the use of 2D Arrays and mathematical operations.");

  // Intialize and load arrays with flight information
  int dArr[ROWS][COLS];

  for (int i = 2; i < ROWS + 2; i++){
    for (int j = 1; j < COLS + 1; j++) {
      dArr[i][j] = pow(i, j);
      cout << setw(8);
      cout << dArr[i][j];
    }
    cout << "\n";
  }

  //Goodbye Message
  displayMessage("Goodbye!");
}
```

Comment: *"I just cant identify what in my code is causing it"* - are you sure that iterating from `2` to `ROWS + 2` on array that has `ROWS` elements is a good idea?

Comment: Umm, because you are accessing elements out of range: `dArr[i][j] = pow(i, j);` ?

Comment: Looks like simple writing outside the bounds of an array.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346806/

Comment: Using all uppercase for constants is a bad habit and antipattern in C++

Answer (score -1):

```
for (int i = 2; i < ROWS + 2; i++){
    for (int j = 1; j < COLS + 1; j++) {
          dArr[i][j] = pow(i, j);
```

You set the max value of ‘i’ and ‘j’ to exceed ROWS and COLS, which you used to set the array dimension with.

Since max position in the array is 1 less than the value used:

int a[9]; // indexes 0 through 8.

So when you attempt to access a position of ROWS or COLS you exceed the array’s size. This translates into a segfault.